# Closed source servers in Europe (Wire) vs open source servers in US (Signal) for E2EE

Tags: privacy, appsec

I've been trying to move family and friends to a Whatsapp alternative, and while Signal is widely regarded as the most secure, it lacks some "candy" that might make it more alluring to people.

Coming upon Wire, and looking in the repository, they seem to implement the mighty Double Ratchet encryption that is also used by Signal (Implemented in C in Signal, Rust in Wire). They also have a good amount of candy - doodling, animated gifs, audio messages and whatnot.

However - their servers are closed source, whereas Signal is entirely open source, both client and server. Yet Signal is US-based. According to wiki - "Open Whisper Systems has set up dozens of servers to handle the encrypted calls in more than 10 countries around the world to minimize latency", but I'm not sure what that entails if they have US servers as well and are a US-based company.  Wire is Swiss-based and claim that their servers are in Europe, but that they use proxies in the US.

My question is, which would you consider more privacy appealing server-wise: open servers by a US company, or closed servers by a European company?

Comment: Sorry Joe but you are still asking for an opinion. It is utterly impossible to give a sensible answer other than expressing an opinion. I guess you could rephrase the question to ask for the known positives and negatives of each option? Even that is fairly opinionated. EU is more privacy focussed than the US with laws to match but open *can* be better.

Comment: The whole point of E2EE is that the server does not matter. The main attack vectors will be implementation mistakes, automatic updates, and failure of users to check device fingerprints. Ask yourself, which platform encourages (and makes easiest) the checking of fingerprints? Which one has many people looking over the code before it is shipped? Are releases signed and verifiable, or could an attacker slip something in? Having open source servers is nice, but gives you almost nothing security-wise. You cannot verify what is actually being run on the servers, or who has access to the servers.